# C++ comparing a string with an array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays

if I have:

```
const string food[] = {"Burgers", "3", "Fries", "Milkshake"}
string word;
cin >> word;
```

How can I compare word with the correct food? or rather, if the user inputs "Fries", how can I compare that with the string array?

Comment: That's correct. If the user enters "Fries" I am trying to figure out how I can compare food[] with word

Comment: An array seems like the wrong structure. I would store the data in a `std::map` to take advantage of the look-up functionality.

Comment: @andre: A `std::set` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Curious if this question is going to bring all the boys to the yard...

Answer (score 7):

With `find`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

auto it = std::find(std::begin(food), std::end(food), word);

if (it != std::end(food))
{
    // found *it
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `find` algorithm from `<algorithm>`:

```
auto found = std::find(std::begin(food), std::end(food), word);
if (found == std::end(food)) {
    // not found
} else {
    // found points to the array element
}
```

or with a loop:

```
for (const auto &item : food) {
    if (item == word) {
        // found it
    }
}
```

although, if you need to do this a lot, it might be better to store the items in a data structure designed for quick searches: `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.