# Understanding find and vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector, find

I'm trying to understand this line of code

```
vector<int>::iterator it = find(list_vector.begin(), list_vector.end(), 5)
```

where I have `vector<int> list_vector;` declared before hand.

What does the 5 do? What does it return? Does it return the 5 if it can find it at the beginning and end? If I wanted to make an if statement, and I wanted to find if the number 10 was in the statement (if it was, return true) how would I go about doing that?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: I think that "RTFM", harsh as it may seem, is the only appropriate answer here...

Comment: "find if the number 10 was in the [if] statement"? Huh?

Comment: I apologize for the "RTFM". I tried looking up the answer and couldn't find anything. I can't seem to do if (vector<int>::iterator it = find(plist.begin(), plist.end(), number) == number) as it is giving errors. Any ideas?

Comment: An iterator mimics a pointer; you'd have to *dereference* it to get back the number. That is, of course, if the iterator isn't `plist.end()` (the iterator equivalent of `NULL`).

Comment: @JakeSmith - that is not a valid syntax in C++. A declaration cannot be part of an expression. If you want to delcare `it` *and* compare it to some value, you must do that in two distinct statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ comparing a string with an array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742637/c-comparing-a-string-with-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
vector<int>::iterator it = find(list_vector.begin(), list_vector.end(), 5)
```

`std::find` searches in the range defined by its first two arguments. It returns an iterator pointing to the first element that matches. If no element matches, it returns its 2nd parameter.

`list_vector.begin()` returns an iterator that points to the first element of `list_vector`.

`list_vector.end()` returns an iterator that points one element beyond the final element of `list_vector`.

`5` is the target of the search. `find()` will look for an element that has the value `5`.

If you'd like to determine if 10 is present anywhere in the vector, do this:

```
if(std::find(list_vector.begin(), list_vector.end(), 10) == list_vector.end())
    std::cout << "No 10, bummer\n";
else
    std::cout << "I found a 10!\n";
```

Or, if you'd like to simultaneously determine if 10 is present *and* determine its location:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find(list_vector.begin(), list_vector.end(), 10);
if(it == list_vector.end())
    std::cout << "No 10\n";
else
    std::cout << "Look what I found: " << *it << "\n";
```

Comment: For the first one, it will search from beginning to the end for 10, how come when you are doing == you can't set it to say, 10, 5, or just some int variable that I let the user enter? It's giving me errors when I try that. for example,  find(list_vector.begin(), list_vector.end(), 10) == number)

Comment: @JakeSmith, `std::find` returns an iterator, not whatever type the third argument is.

Comment: how do you find next occurrence using find

Comment: @MuhammadUmer -  `iterator it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 10); std::cout << "First find: " << *it << "\n"; it = std::find(it, v.end(), 10); std::cout << "Second find: " << *it << "\n";`