# IF condition comparing a substring to a string array produces error in C++

Tags: c++

I am just a beginner in C++ and I am trying to scan the first character of an inputted string for vowels using simple syntaxes

I tried using array of strings for vowels

```
string vowels[] = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
string word;
string first;

cout<< "enter a word: ";
cin>>word;
cout<<endl;

first = word.substr(0,1);

cout<<first<<endl;

if (first == vowels)
{
    cout << "NO!"<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<< word <<endl;
}


return 0;
```

if condition yields an error:

Invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') and 'string *' (aka 'basic_string, allocator > *'))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ comparing a string with an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742637/c-comparing-a-string-with-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to too see if a word(first) is identical to an array (vowels).

What you need to be doing is check if each character inside the word is also contained inside the vowel array.

A simple function do this would look something like.

```
bool insideArray( std::string aWord, std::string aArray[] )
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< aWord.length(); i++ ) 
    {
        //Use the find function.
        bool exists = std::find( std:begin(aArray, std:end(aArray), aWord[i]) != std:end(aWord[i])
        if (exists) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    // reached the end, and have never returned true, so no character from aWord is inside aArray
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to compare `first` to each element of `vowels[]`.

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<vowels.size(); i++) {
    if(first == vowels[i])
        // ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Member reference base type 'string [5]' is not a structure or union

Comment: `vowels` is an array, so `vowels.size()` won't work. That said, @SydneyBorn should prefer `std::vector<std::string>` over a raw array.

Comment: array::size() is added in C++11. Perhaps you could use `(sizeof(vowels)/sizeof(*vowels))` to determine the array length instead.

Comment: @LegendofPedro OP is using a raw array, so `std::array::size` won't help either. A better way to get the length of a raw array (and any std container) is `std::size` (since C++17)